# Possible Reasons for SSIS Package to Process Every Second Row of Dataset

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Firstly sorry that I can't get really specific, as SSIS packages may get very complicated and are awful to describe.

My sceanrio requires a CSV to be processed after validation against other tables and stored into several tables in a SQL database. My result is that only every second row of my CSV gets processed on the target system. The test and dev environments (which are equivalent set up) behave as expected and store all rows.

What are possible reasons for my target system to behave different? What are the most possible mistakes e.g. oversee/oversight?

Answer (score 1):

In the flat file connection manager check whether the header row to skip is zero.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I double checked that value at all connectors. I was already considering some blindness here, but no. It's set zero. Thanks for your contribution anyway! Hope to find a solution :S

Comment: Ok understood, btw can you check text qualifiers, row decimeters are set correctly. sometimes if a delimiter comes with in the value it might cause such behavior

Comment: Will check on that the next time I get on the system and report back here. It's totally confusing, since it is working on both, the dev and integration system but not on uat or production...